# Installlation of react native on android

Tags: android, windows, react-native

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> Cannot access output property 'cacheDir' of task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking for more details.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\newapp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug-mergeJavaRes\zip-cache\Tmls8pS15kWK_j3hDr21nYRdvbE=' as it does not exist.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

All things like i restatrde whole server change the location of my app